# Slicer problems

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have constructed a large pivot table and attempted to put some slicers on. Sheets will not

1. let me choose the specific column I wish to slice on,
2. when I have a slicer like "Name" the slicer only shows me eight names of the several hundred in the sheet, and
3. the slicer for grade...1 - 7 does not see grade five.

I'm an Excel guy and not proficient with sheets, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes, if we had access to your file we would find a solution faster

Comment: How do I upload afile so you can see it?

Comment: write his link here, so that we can access it

Comment: Questions on this site should be self contained, considering this please describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet structure and pivot table, add some sample data and the corresponding expected results. You might also include a link shared with anyone with the link but bear in might that  your Google Account name will be visible on Google Drive by the spreadsheet viewers and they might also find your email.